# Is "anomaly" a positive/negative word?

Tags: grammar, syntactic-analysis, connotation

Is using the word "Anomaly" in a positive sense okay? For instance, to denote someone/thing with characteristics of an outlier, sth that stands apart. I'm not sure because I've only heard of the word in a negative context.

Comment: Welcome to EL&U. There can be an 'anomaly' - in the midst of a series of experimental results - which is actually the only genuine figure. In which case it is, as you say, a positive thing.

Comment: An example of what @NigelJ describes is the hunt for the Higgs Boson - they were looking for anomalies at specific energy levels, hoping that one of them would turn out to be the hard-to-find particle they'd been looking for.

Comment: If I woke up tomorrow to find my bank had transferred £1,000,000 into my account from their own money because their systems erroneously thought it was really my money and they insisted the transfer was correct and the money was mine I'd find that to be 1) a serious anomaly and 2) _incredibly_ positive.

Answer (score 1):

There must be at least a negative connotation, as at least one dictionary [[CED](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/anomaly)] gives a negative denotation:

> **anomaly**: a person or thing that is different from what is usual, or not in agreement with something else and therefore not satisfactory.

[RHK Webster's](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/anomaly) included 'abnormality' in its definitions:

> **anomaly** ...
>
> 1. a deviation from the common type, rule, arrangement, or form; irregularity; abnormality.
> 2. someone or something anomalous.
> 3. an unexpected, unusual, or strange condition, situation, or quality.

as does AHD:

> **anomaly**
>
> 1. Deviation or departure from the normal or common order, form, or rule.
> 2. One that is peculiar, irregular, abnormal, or difficult to classify

The facts that ODO say does not give even a hint of a 'negative' flavour, and almost all dictionaries offer non-negative senses, cannot totally remove the negative connotation. This does not mean that judicious use is wrong; 'anomalous readings' would rarely generate the negative flavour.

Answer (score 0):

The word itself is neutral, so it may be also used in a positive context.

Comment: Hi, Carol. Can you point to a dictionary definition that presents _anomaly_ in a thoroughly neutral way? Edwin Ashworth's answer cites definitions that include such elements as "not satisfactory," "deviation," "abnormality," "peculiar," and "irregular," and "strange"—all of which seem to hint at a negative interpretation of difference.

Comment: @SvenYargs I don't see an inherent negative connotation in "anomaly" or most of the synonyms you list. I'll grant you "not satisfactory" and "abnormality", but the others can be neutral or even positive.

Answer (score 0):

An interesting article, by Alok Jha, using 'anomaly' in a **positive sense**, appeared in [The Guardian](https://www.theguardian.com/commentisfree/2011/nov/25/science-column-anomalies-einstein-newton) entitled :

> Anomalies are crucial for bettering our understanding of the universe

and in it he outlines the anomaly which Einstein noticed, a conflict between James Clerk Maxwell's light experiments and Isaac Newton's equations. This led to Einstein's Special Theory of Relativity and then on to his General Theory of Relativity.

However, Alok Jha's article begins with the more recant anomaly observed by the Gran Sasso lab at CERN, where neutrinos were observe to arrive later than they should after travelling through 450 miles of rock.

If confirmed, this anomaly could lead to a revision of *Einstein's work*.